How do I calculate the volume of a horizontal cylindrical tank in c++?
I have been trying to use a code to calculate the volume of the liquid in a horizontal cylindrical tank.
I will use an esp32 micro controller to take sensor data and calculate the volume of water in my tank.
All measurements in centimeters.
This is what I have been trying from other formulas from the internet, but keep getting way out calculations.
double radius=100;
double height=50; // the depth of the water in the tank this will be my sensor reading
double length=450;
double volume;

volume = (3.14*radius*radius)-((radius*radius)*acos((radius-height)/radius))+((radius-height)*
           (sqrt(2*radius*height-(height*height))));`

When using an online calculator, the volume generated from this formula and the one from online calculator differ (all measurements in CM).

Volume of a Cylinder

FYI, the calculation of a tank, assuming perfect cylinder, has nothing to do with c++, or arduino.  Always, write the program on a desktop platform and get it working before porting to Arduino or any other embedded system.  Desktop platforms are always easier to debug on.

volume = (3.14*radius*radius)-((radius*radius)*acos((radius-height)/radius))+((radius-height)*(sqrt(2*radius*height-(height*height)))); -- Let's ask you -- which part of this formula do you believe is giving the incorrect result, thus throwing the answer off?  You don't know, because you stuffed everything on one line.  If you want to debug this, break up this line into several variables, then inspect each one to see if the sub-result is correct.

You might also want to draw a diagram, preferably showing the cross-sectional area only part full of water.

@ThomasMatthews They specify in the question that it's horizontal.

You don't have the length anywhere in your formula, which you need to be able to calculate the volume.

@ThomasJager, which is why I withdrew my comment.  I still have a calculus based image going through my head though.

https://www.mathopenref.com/cylindervolpartial.html


Half cross-sectional area occupied by water = area of segment – area of triangle
So,

volume = cross-sectional area x length
So,

where

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double partFilledCylinderVolume( double r, double h, double L )
{
   double theta = acos( 1 - h / r );
   return L * r * r * ( theta - cos( theta ) * sin( theta ) );
}

int main()
{
   double radius = 100;
   double height = 50;
   double length = 450;

   cout << partFilledCylinderVolume( radius, height, length ) << " cubic centimetres" << '\n';
}

Output:
2.76383e+06 cubic centimetres


thank you so much I added this to my Arduino IDE and it worked perfectly I only added the convertion to liters .Thank you for posting the formula and explenation it helped.

Like @lastchance good answer yet with fewer trig functions.
double partFilledCylinderVolume(double r, double h, double L) {
   double opposite = sqrt(h*(r*2 - h));  // sqrt(r*r - (r-h)*(r-h))
   double sin_theta = opposite/r;
   double cos_theta = 1 - h / r;
   
   double theta = acos(cos_theta);

   // return L * r * r * ( theta - cos( theta ) * sin( theta ) );
   return L * r * r * (theta - cos_theta * sin_theta);
}

